# Error: Failed building wheel for quadprog (Ubuntu, python)

Tags: quadprog

In macos I did not receive that error, in Windows I had to install Microsoft Visual Studio but on Linux I do not know how to solve this.

The error shows after I type to the terminal:

```
pip install qpsolvers
```

I tried many ways and I ask for help.

Comment: Please share the error you get on Linux. Have you installed `build-essential`?

Comment: Please edit your question to show Ubuntu version → *Edit* → https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70926421/edit ........... Example Ubuntu 20.04 : `pip install qpsolvers` → "Successfully installed qpsolvers-1.8.0".

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing g++; this should work:

```
apt-get install g++
```

This worked for me:

```
conda install -c conda-forge gxx
```